# PHP Record sound and upload php with progressbar

Tags: php, ajax, audio, upload

I used the code at the link for recording audio and upload to server.
I found some upload progressbar codes but could not merge with this code.
Audio records may be 30-40 mb and upload takes long time.
How can I add upload status for this code below?

https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/

````
    var upload = document.createElement('a');
    upload.href="#";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
    upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function(e) {
              if(this.readyState === 4) {
                  console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
              }
          };
          
          var fd=new FormData();
          fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
          fd.append("filename",blob, 'audiofile');
          xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
          xhr.send(fd);
          alert('Uploaded');
    }) ```
````

Comment: Refer the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event)
{
    var progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
    
    console.log('Progress: ' + progress);
});
```